# Transform Matrix by 4 vectors?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, geometry, directx

For 4*4 transform matrix m,if represented internally using 4 vectors x, y, z, w

For translation part, is it

```
w.x = t.x ; w.y = t.y ; w.z = t.z
```

or

```
x.w = t.x; y.w = t.y; z.w = t.z;
```

I am confused, please help.

Comment: Have you read an answer to your another qwestion?? You have to specify more about conventions used.

Answer (score 0):

It's the first case. the follow picture translate point(x,y,z) to new point(x',y',z').

[image]

Matrix in DirctX was stored as row-major, so here

```
vector x = [1 0 0 0]
vector y = [0 1 0 0]
vector z = [0 0 1 0]
vector w = [tx ty tz 1]
```

[Transform in Direct3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)